# Window doesn't update unless i move it

Tags: c++, windows, qt, directx-11, qt5.4

Okay so while i was on holiday i was working on my laptop and i decided to make the move from Win32 API to Qt and everything was working fine. Until i got back on my PC, that is. This problem only occurs on my PC and not on my laptop i have used win merge to try and detect any differences and there are NONE.

The way i have implemented this is i have a GameView class derived from QWidget and I've overridden the paintEngine function to do nothing and i set the DirectX HWND to the WId of the game view QWidget.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated

This gets called during initialization to create the window

```
bool Engine::CreateDisplay()
{
m_pQtApp = new QApplication(m_nArgCount, m_pArgV);

m_pGameWindow = new GameWindow(this);
m_pGameWindow->show();

m_pGameView = new GameView(this);
m_pGameView->setParent(m_pGameWindow);
m_pGameView->show();
m_pGameView->resize(800, 600);
m_pGameWindow->setCentralWidget((QWidget*)m_pGameView);

return true;
}
```

Then once everything is initialized this gets called

```
int Engine::StartGameLoop()
{
m_bIsRunning = true;
m_pCurrentWorld->BeginPlay();

//MSG msg {};
while(m_bIsRunning)
{
    /*if(PeekMessage(&msg, m_hWnd, 0, 0, PM_REMOVE))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }*/
    m_pQtApp->processEvents();

    if(m_bIsRunning)
    {
        //m_pGameView->update();
        Update();
        Render();
    }
}

m_pCurrentWorld->EndPlay();

return 0;
}
```

This is the resize event I modified

```
void GameView::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent* pEvent)
{
if(m_pEngine->GetGraphics())
    m_pEngine->GetGraphics()->SetResolution(pEvent->size().width(), pEvent->size().height());

//QWidget::resizeEvent(pEvent);
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow! Could you post a sample of the code that isn't working? That will make it easier for others to answer your question.

Comment: Okay, now i'm really confused. it's working but i havent changed anything.

I added QWidget::resizeEvent(pEvent); to the bottom of my resizeEvent in the gameview class and it started working but i removed it and it still works

Comment: I would like to know what was causing the problem incase it occurs again so ill ad my code to the question

Comment: Off-topic: *"i have use win merge to try and…"*. You don't use version control? [Start using it *now*](https://git-scm.com).

Comment: i think the `while` loop is the problem. Because if you do not use multi-threading and do not call processEvents specifically, your ui event loop is stucked until you are out of your loop and function

Comment: I checked to see if everything was getting updated and it was so processEvents was being called around 60 times per second

Comment: @Zeta I do, I use perforce which is how i got it from my laptop to my pc but you cant easily mass diff afaik

Comment: @KieranChandler: [`p4 diff @...`](http://www.perforce.com/perforce/r15.1/manuals/cmdref/p4_diff.html)

Comment: I stand corrected thanks Zeta